# Flutter: Unit Testing a Cubit issues

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, bloc, bloc-test, flutter-cubit

I have been trying to set up unit testing for my cubit but bloc test seems to be having issues. Just trying to check the initial state of the values works just fine with regular test but as soon as I try to the same thing with bloc test it spits out fail with the actual being an empty list at [0] and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Nothing on the internet is helpful with this error.

```
//passes
test('initial state of SettingsCubit', () {
  expect(
      settingsCubit.state,
      SettingsState(
          notificationsEnabled: false,
          gpsEnabled: false,
          celsiusEnabled: false,
          expandNavigation: false,
          breakingNewsNotifications: false,
          trendingNotifications: false,
          liveRemindersNotifications: false,
          sportsNotifications: false));
});

//fails
blocTest(
  'initial state of SettingsCubit',
  build: () => SettingsCubit(),
  expect: () => [
    SettingsState(
      expandNavigation: false,
      gpsEnabled: false,
      celsiusEnabled: false,
      notificationsEnabled: false,
      breakingNewsNotifications: false,
      trendingNotifications: false,
      liveRemindersNotifications: false,
      sportsNotifications: false,
    )
  ],
);
```

Error:

```
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 193:9   testBloc.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                   _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart         testBloc.<fn>
dart:async                                   runZonedGuarded
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 172:9   testBloc
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 140:11  blocTest.<fn>
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 139:26  blocTest.<fn>
Expected: [
            SettingsState:SettingsState(expandNavigation: false, gpsEnabled: false, celsiusEnabled: false, notificationsEnabled: false,breakingNewsNotifications: false, trendingNotifications: false, liveRemindersNotifications: false, sportsNotifications: false)
          ]
  Actual: []
   Which: at location [0] is [] which shorter than expected
```

SettingsCubit and SettingsState code is at:
[Flutter BLoC Test failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582768/flutter-bloc-test-failures)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the initial state of your Cubit, you should use the first way (the one that worked for you).

The reason why the second version of the same test (`blocTest` one) does not work is described in the `bloc_test` documentation:

> [expect] is an optional `Function` that returns a `Matcher` which the
> `bloc` under test is expected to emit after [act] is executed.

Meaning, you should put all the state **changes** inside the `expect` method. But now, you are just creating a BLoC without executing any action after that, your state does not change, hence the actual result - a list of expected state changes - is empty.

Comment: I actually got it all working. It seemed to be an issue when using HydratedBloc mixin on my cubit. Even when I was invoking a state change with act, it would still give me errors. I understand now about the empty list if there is no state change. Thank you for your answer!